# Distributed nested loop algorithms

Tags: algorithm, distributed, distributed-computing

Lets say I have the following code running on each worker in my distributed system with a master and slave architecture:

```
for (i in set1) {
    for (j in set2) {
        //Some computation based on i, j
        //Store the results in some data structure for each i, j
    }
}
```

Now each worker sends its set of results for each `i,j` to the master which accumulates the results from all the workers ('reduce' over the results for each `i,j` pair).

Now the sizes of `set1, set2` are too high making it impossible to run the nested loop on the workers and generate values for all possible i,j and send them over to the master. I am thinking of streaming intermediate results. Any suggestions on distributing this nested loop structure.

Note: Each worker has its own copy of the sets: `set1, set2`. Further, we don't have any ordering on what the pairs of `i,j` each worker returns.

We just know that the number of unique `i,j` pairs can't fit in memory on any single node (not even the master).

Looking for suggestions on algorithms designed for such a use case.

Comment: What do `set1` and `set2` contain? The sets are different for each slave? What is the _type_ of the result which you finally want to reduce?

Comment: Lets say `set1` and `set2` contain strings. Then each worker computes some double value for each `i,j | i in set1, j in set2` which is sent back to the master. The master then simply accumulates the final double value (reduce  - addition) for each `i,j` and returns the final results (essentially a map from strings - `i,j` - to double value)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I think it will make a difference if you tell what is being done in the section of your nested loop `//Some computation based on i, j`?

Comment: Basically we lookup some database for counts of `i` and `j` (different tables) and then sum them up (weighted sum) to get the `double` value for the key `i,j`

Comment: Why don't you do the join at the DB too instead of just doing the lookup?

Comment: I have abstracted the problem due to non-disclosure issues. Lets just assume that for some reason we cannot do a join and the counts for `i` and `j` need to be retrieved separately and the value for `i,j` is the computed using the individual values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92310/discussion-between-displayname-and-vineet-goel).